# How to fix brew doctor output with double question marks

Tags: macos, homebrew

Running `brew doctor` the output is too long for the shell. Below is what I can still reach.
Any idea what the warning (or error) for these might be and how to fix it?

*Some system info:*

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.0.5-18-g433cd83-dirty
...
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/bin/ruby
...
macOS: 10.15.7-x86_64
```

*Note: I deleted several lines due to reaching the comment's character limit. I marked them with `#` and left an empty line after.*

```bash
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.90.0/lib/rubocop/cop/layout/rescue_ensure_alignment.rb
  # ~500 more lines of 
  # ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-0.90.0/lib/...

  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-performance-1.10.1/config/default.yml
  # 50 more lines of
  # ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-performance-1.10.1/lib/...

  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-rails-2.9.1/config/default.yml
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-rails-2.9.1/lib/rubocop-rails.rb
  # 90 more lines of
  # ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-rails-2.9.1/lib/...

  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-rspec-2.2.0/config/default.yml
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-rspec-2.2.0/lib/rubocop-rspec.rb
  # ~100 more lines of
  # ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-rspec-2.2.0/lib/...

  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-sorbet-0.5.1/config/default.yml
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-sorbet-0.5.1/lib/rubocop-sorbet.rb
  # 20 more lines of
  # ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rubocop-sorbet-0.5.1/lib/...

  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ruby-macho-2.5.0/lib/macho.rb
  # 10 more lines of
  # ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ruby-macho-2.5.0/lib/...
  
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ruby-progressbar-1.10.1/lib/ruby-progressbar.rb
  # ~20 more lines of
  # ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ruby-progressbar-1.10.1/...

  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ruby-progressbar-1.11.0/lib/ruby-progressbar.rb
  # ~20 more lines of
  # ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ruby-progressbar-1.11.0/lib/...

  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/simplecov_json_formatter-0.1.2/lib/simplecov_json_formatter.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/simplecov_json_formatter-0.1.2/lib/simplecov_json_formatter/result_exporter.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/simplecov_json_formatter-0.1.2/lib/simplecov_json_formatter/result_hash_formatter.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/simplecov_json_formatter-0.1.2/lib/simplecov_json_formatter/source_file_formatter.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/simplecov_json_formatter-0.1.2/lib/simplecov_json_formatter/version.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-stub-0.2.0/lib/sorbet-runtime-stub.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo.rb
  # ~90 more lines of
  # ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/...

  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/warning-1.2.0/lib/warning.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/webrick-1.7.0/lib/webrick.rb
  # ~90 more lines of
  # ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/webrick-1.7.0/lib/...

  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/error.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/explicit_namespace.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/gem_inflector.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/inflector.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/real_mod_name.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/registry.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/version.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby-version
  ?? Library/Homebrew/version.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/version.rbi
  ?? Library/Homebrew/version/null.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/version/parser.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/warnings.rb
  ?? Library/Homebrew/warnings.rbi
  ?? Library/README.md
  ?? README.md
  ?? completions/README.md
  ?? completions/bash/brew
  ?? completions/fish/brew.fish
  ?? completions/internal_commands_list.txt
  ?? completions/zsh/_brew
  ?? docs/Acceptable-Casks.md
  ?? docs/Acceptable-Formulae.md
  ?? docs/Adding-Software-to-Homebrew.md
  ?? docs/Analytics.md
  ?? docs/Bottles.md
  ?? docs/Brew-Livecheck.md
  ?? docs/Brew-Test-Bot-For-Core-Contributors.md
  ?? docs/Brew-Test-Bot.md
  ?? docs/Building-Against-Non-Homebrew-Dependencies.md
  ?? docs/C++-Standard-Libraries.md
  ?? docs/CNAME
  ?? docs/Checksum_Deprecation.md
  ?? docs/Common-Issues-for-Core-Contributors.md
  ?? docs/Common-Issues.md
  ?? docs/Creating-a-Homebrew-Issue.md
  ?? docs/Custom-GCC-and-cross-compilers.md
  ?? docs/Deprecating-Disabling-and-Removing-Formulae.md
  ?? docs/Diagram-Guidelines.md
  ?? docs/External-Commands.md
  ?? docs/FAQ.md
  ?? docs/Formula-Cookbook.md
  ?? docs/Gemfile
  ?? docs/Gemfile.lock
  ?? docs/Gems,-Eggs-and-Perl-Modules.md
  ?? docs/Homebrew-Governance.md
  ?? docs/Homebrew-and-Java.md
  ?? docs/Homebrew-and-Python.md
  ?? docs/Homebrew-homebrew-core-Merge-Checklist.md
  ?? docs/Homebrew-linuxbrew-core-Maintainer-Guide.md
  ?? docs/Homebrew-on-Linux.md
  ?? docs/How-To-Open-a-Homebrew-Pull-Request.md
  ?? docs/How-to-Build-Software-Outside-Homebrew-with-Homebrew-keg-only-Dependencies.md
  ?? docs/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap.md
  ?? docs/Installation.md
  ?? docs/Interesting-Taps-and-Forks.md
  ?? docs/Kickstarter-Supporters.md
  ?? docs/License-Guidelines.md
  ?? docs/Maintainer-Guidelines.md
  ?? docs/Maintainers-Avoiding-Burnout.md
  ?? docs/Manpage.md
  ?? docs/Migrating-A-Formula-To-A-Tap.md
  ?? docs/New-Maintainer-Checklist.md
  ?? docs/Node-for-Formula-Authors.md
  ?? docs/Prose-Style-Guidelines.md
  ?? docs/Python-for-Formula-Authors.md
  ?? docs/Querying-Brew.md
  ?? docs/README.md
  ?? docs/Rakefile
  ?? docs/Releases.md
  ?? docs/Rename-A-Formula.md
  ?? docs/Shell-Completion.md
  ?? docs/Taps.md
  ?? docs/Tips-N'-Tricks.md
  ?? docs/Troubleshooting.md
  ?? docs/Typechecking.md
  ?? docs/Updating-Software-in-Homebrew.md
  ?? docs/Versions.md
  ?? docs/Xcode.md
  ?? docs/_config.yml
  ?? docs/assets/img/docs/analytics.png
  ?? docs/assets/img/docs/brew-test-bot-failed-pr.png
  ?? docs/assets/img/docs/brew-test-bot-passed-pr.png
  ?? docs/assets/img/docs/brew-test-bot-triggered-pr.png
  ?? docs/assets/img/docs/managing-pull-requests.drawio.svg
  ?? docs/robots.txt
  ?? docs/vale-styles/Homebrew/Abbreviations.yml
  ?? docs/vale-styles/Homebrew/OxfordComma.yml
  ?? docs/vale-styles/Homebrew/Pronouns.yml
  ?? docs/vale-styles/Homebrew/README.md
  ?? docs/vale-styles/Homebrew/Spacing.yml
  ?? docs/vale-styles/Homebrew/Terms.yml
  ?? docs/vale-styles/Homebrew/Titles.yml
  ?? docs/vale-styles/Homebrew/Trademarks.yml
  ?? manpages/README.md
  ?? manpages/brew.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing `brew update-reset`. Do make a note of the following, however:

```
❯ brew help update-reset
Usage: brew update-reset [repository ...]

Fetch and reset Homebrew and all tap repositories (or any specified
repository) using git(1) to their latest origin/HEAD.

Note: this will destroy all your uncommitted or committed changes.
```

Comment: Thanks @theoretical-economist that did the trick removing most of the above "Uncommitted files", enough to see the warnings. The one above the remaining uncommited files suggested to stash those changes if they weren't from me (which they were not)
`cd /usr/local/Homebrew && git stash && git clean -d -f`.